# informix 14.10 How to "select" returns a specific phrase such as None or blank instead of no result

Tags: select, informix

I have a query like this:

```
  select c1 , ( select d1 from table2 where dt) from table1 where  ct
```

but if there is no d1 under condition dt i have no result but i have a reult like this:

```
--c1               d1
value1       NONE or  Blank
value 2      NONE or  Blank    
  .                .
  .                .
```

Can anybody Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NVL function can be used to return either of its two arguments depending on whether the first evaluates to NULL. So your example query could be written as:

```
select c1 , NVL(( select d1 from table2 where dt), "NONE") from table1 where ct
```

The data types of the two arguments need to be compatible, for example both character or both numeric.
More information can be found at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1445.htm